# Having problems opening a new WPF window with C#

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I'm new to C# and I am trying to learn! But I've been stuck trying to get a new window to open! I've read various other similar questions here on StackOverflow and googled but found nothing!

I have two windows. One called `MainWindow` and another called `ChildForm`. I use the follow code on a button I named `openNewForm`.

```
private void openNewForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChildForm f2 = new ChildForm();
        this.Hide();
        f2.ShowDialog();
    }
```

From my understanding, this is the standard way of opening a new window or form. I have seen some tutorials use `var f2 = new ChildForm();` however. When trying to run my application, I get the following error message.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line
>   Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ChildForm' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) WpfApplication1 ... 38

I think this could possibly be a reference issue, but I am not entirely sure. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In what namespace is `ChildForm` and in which is your current form? In which assembly are they?

Comment: @PatrickHofman This is Visual Studio 2015. The form running the code is named `MainWindow`, the namespace is `WpfApplication1`. The namespace of my second form is `ChildForm`.

Comment: That is not the namespace of your `ChildForm`, is it?

Comment: @PatrickHofman, The namespace of `ChildForm.xaml` was `Window1`, but is now `ChildForm`.

Comment: That is the class name. What is the namespace?

Comment: @PatrickHofman I believe it is `ChildForm`, is [this not a namespace](http://i.imgur.com/Wduppzw.png)? I am not sure.

Comment: Yes, it is. You are confusing yourself and me by changing the namespace to the same as your class name. Try change the namespace to `WpfApplication1`.

Comment: Thanks, I got it working. There was some mismatch due to the renaming in xaml file. Some `Window1` text was left over.

Answer (score 2):

Consider creating a window for your dialog and using it like this.

```
public class DialogWindow : Window
{
    // Your custom dialog window.
}
```

Call it like so:

```
      DialogWindow w = new DialogWindow();

      if(w.ShowDialog() != false)
      {
          // Do stuff here

      }
```

Comment: No he shouldn't since this is WPF application, not WinForms.

Comment: The Name of the reference type totally threw me off. :)